# Adding a MouseListener to a panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I am trying to add the mouse actions to my panel. 
This is what the program is supposed to do:

> Write a program that allows the user to specify a triangle with three mouse presses. After the first mouse press, draw a small dot. After the second mouse press, draw a line joining the first two points. After the third mouse press, draw the entire triangle. The fourth mouse press erases the old triangle and starts a new one.

Comment: Well, I guessing to start with `createCenterPanel().addMouseListener(new MouseListen())` might be a good start

Comment: I'm also guessing that you'll want to have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: *"I am trying to add the mouse actions to my panel."* So .. have at it! When you have an actual question, get back to us with a single, clear, explicit question accompanied with a [mcve].

Comment: @AndrewThompson The OP deleted their code - for some reason :/

Comment: I deleted my code because it was a homework assignment and I did not want students in my class to copy and paste my code

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend you start by having a read through [How to Write a Mouse Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). When ever you get stuck, these tutorials (and the JavaDocs) are the best place to get started

The "immediate" answer to your question is, you need to register an instance of the `MouseListener` with your component, maybe something like...

```
private JPanel createCenterPanel() {

    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListen());
    //panel.setLayout(null);


    return panel;
}
```

This will "answer" your immediate issue.

However, you'll find it hard to try and marry up the actions of the `MouseListener` with the panel, which needs to paint the results.

A better solution might be to start with a `JPanel` which manages it's own `MouseListener`

Also, `Graphics g = panel.getGraphics()` isn't how custom painting should be performed.  Take a look at [Performing custom painting for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

So, instead, it might look something more like...

```
public class TrianglePanel extends JPanel {

    private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>(3);

    public TrianglePanel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseListen());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

        if (points.size() < 1) {
            return;
        }
        for (int index = 0; index < points.size(); index++) {
            Point nextPoint = points.get(index);
            g.fillOval(nextPoint.x - 2, nextPoint.y - 2, 4, 4);
        }

        Point startPoint = points.get(0);
        Point lastPoint = startPoint;
        for (int index = 1; index < points.size(); index++) {
            Point nextPoint = points.get(index);
            g.drawLine(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
            lastPoint = nextPoint;
        }
        g.drawLine(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    }

    class MouseListen extends MouseAdapter {

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (points.size() < 3) {
                points.add(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere you instantiate class MouseListen. Also you need to call addMouseListener().

Here are lines from something I wrote a while back that worked:

```
public class ColorPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

   . . .

ColorPanel(JTextField jTextFieldColor) {
    super();
    this.jTextField = jTextFieldColor;
    addMouseListener(this);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("Instance of ColorPanel clicked.");
    jColorChooser = new JColorChooser(this.getBackground());
    this.add(jColorChooser);
    int retval = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            jColorChooser,
            "JOptionPane Example : ",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if (retval == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        jTextField.setText(Utils.hexStringFromColor(jColorChooser.getColor()));
    }
}
```

See the tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html.

Also, based on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html, you might be able to have your JFrame implement the MouseListener, which would make your code even simpler. (You wouldn't need class MouseListen at all.)

A quick grep though past Java code I've written confirms you could

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener
```

so you might want to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the listener object with the Jpanel using the **addMouseListener** method.
More info;

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 0):

cam, given what you're doing, I hopped on my "work machine" and grabbed this code. It draws a rectangle on top of an image, and the rectangle only shows up after you release the mouse (it's a work in progress, unpaid, done in my spare time for stuff my employer might like). But since you're looking ahead to drawing, etc., here it is.

Uses a JDialog because I wanted it to be modal; don't let that bother you.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class RectSelectGUI extends JDialog implements MouseListener, ActionListener, WindowListener {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                public int overheadWd;
                public int overheadHt;
                public ImageJPanel imagePanel;
                private JMenu jMenuSelection;
                private JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
                private Dimension mouseDownLoc;
                private String errorString;

                public RectSelectGUI(String imgFileName) {
                                initComponents(imgFileName);
                }

                private void initComponents(String imgFileName) {

                                imagePanel = new ImageJPanel(imgFileName);
                                jMenuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
                                jMenuSelection = new JMenu();
        JMenuItem jMenuItemSave = new JMenuItem();
        jMenuItemSave.setActionCommand("Save");
        jMenuItemSave.addActionListener(this);
        jMenuItemSave.setText("Save");
        jMenuSelection.add(jMenuItemSave);
        JMenuItem jMenuItemCancel = new JMenuItem();
        jMenuItemCancel.setActionCommand("Cancel");
        jMenuItemCancel.addActionListener(this);
        jMenuItemCancel.setText("Cancel");
        jMenuSelection.add(jMenuItemCancel);

                                mouseDownLoc = new Dimension();
                                errorString = "No selection";

                                imagePanel.addMouseListener(this);

                                this.setModal(true);
                                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                                this.addWindowListener(this);

                                GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new GroupLayout(imagePanel);
                                imagePanel.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
                                jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                                                                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 524, Short.MAX_VALUE));
                                jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                                                                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 370, Short.MAX_VALUE));

                                jMenuSelection.setText("Selection");
                                jMenuBar1.add(jMenuSelection);

                                setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

                                GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
                                getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
                                layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                                                                                                .addComponent(imagePanel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                                                .addContainerGap()));
                                layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                                                                                                .addComponent(imagePanel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                                                .addContainerGap()));

                                pack();

                                overheadWd = this.getWidth() - imagePanel.getWidth();
                                overheadHt = this.getHeight() - imagePanel.getHeight();

                }

                public String getSelectionString() {
                                if (errorString.isEmpty()) {
                                                double rectWd = (double) imagePanel.rectWd;
                                                double rectHt = (double) imagePanel.rectHt;
                                                double rectX = (double) imagePanel.rectX;
                                                double rectY = (double) imagePanel.rectY;
                                                if (Math.abs(RectSelect.displayFactor - 1.0) > 0.001) {
                                                                System.out.println("Adjusting by displayFactor (" + RectSelect.displayFactor + ")");
                                                                rectWd /= RectSelect.displayFactor;
                                                                rectHt /= RectSelect.displayFactor;
                                                                rectX /= RectSelect.displayFactor;
                                                                rectY /= RectSelect.displayFactor;
                                                }
                                                return Math.round(rectWd) + "x" + Math.round(rectHt) + "+" + Math.round(rectX) + "+" + Math.round(rectY);
                                } else {
                                                return "ERROR: " + errorString;
                                }
                }


                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                                mouseDownLoc.setSize(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                                Dimension mouseUpLoc = new Dimension(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
                                if (mouseDownLoc.width < mouseUpLoc.width) {
                                                imagePanel.rectX = mouseDownLoc.width;
                                                imagePanel.rectWd = mouseUpLoc.width - mouseDownLoc.width;
                                } else {
                                                imagePanel.rectX = mouseUpLoc.width;
                                                imagePanel.rectWd = mouseDownLoc.width - mouseUpLoc.width;
                                }
                                if (mouseDownLoc.height < mouseUpLoc.height) {
                                                imagePanel.rectY = mouseDownLoc.height;
                                                imagePanel.rectHt = mouseUpLoc.height - mouseDownLoc.height;
                                } else {
                                                imagePanel.rectY = mouseUpLoc.height;
                                                imagePanel.rectHt = mouseDownLoc.height - mouseUpLoc.height;
                                }
                                imagePanel.haveNewRect = true;
                                imagePanel.repaint();
                                errorString = "";
                }

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                String cmd = evt.getActionCommand();
                                switch (cmd) {
                                case "Save":
                                                break;
                                case "Cancel":
                                                errorString = "Cancelled";
                                                break;
                                default:
                                                System.out.println("Unknown action command " + cmd);
                                }
                                this.setVisible(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                                errorString = "Cancelled";
                                this.setVisible(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                                try {
                                                Thread.sleep(100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                                }
                                this.repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

}


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageJPanel extends JPanel {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                public Image localImage;
                private int origWd;
                private int origHt;
                private int displayWd;
                private int displayHt;
                public int rectX;
                public int rectY;
                public int rectWd;
                public int rectHt;
                public boolean haveNewRect;
                private Toolkit toolkit;

                ImageJPanel(String imageFileName) {
                                toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                                localImage = toolkit.getImage(imageFileName);
                }

                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g1D) {
                                Graphics2D g;
                                g = (Graphics2D) g1D;
                                // Draw the image using the Graphics object provided
                                g.drawImage(localImage, 0, 0, getDisplayWd(), getDisplayHt(), null);
                                /*
                                * Optional label.
                                Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 24);
                                g1D.setFont(font);
                                FontMetrics metrics = g1D.getFontMetrics();
                                int ht = metrics.getHeight();
                                int wd = metrics.stringWidth(this.imageFileName);
                                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                                g.fillRect(this.getWidth() - wd - 10, this.getHeight() - ht, wd + 10, ht);
                                g1D.setColor(new Color(55, 11, 160));
                                g1D.drawString(this.imageFileName, this.getWidth() - wd - 10, this.getHeight() - ht + 20);
                    */

                                // Draw a selection rectangle if requested.
                                if (haveNewRect) {
                                                g.drawRect(rectX, rectY, rectWd, rectHt);
                                                haveNewRect = false;
                                }
                }

                public int getDisplayWd() {
                                return displayWd;
                }

                public void setDisplayWd(int displayWd) {
                                this.displayWd = displayWd;
                }

                public int getDisplayHt() {
                                return displayHt;
                }

                public void setDisplayHt(int displayHt) {
                                this.displayHt = displayHt;
                }

                public int getOrigWd() {
                                return origWd;
                }

                public void setOrigWd(int origWd) {
                                this.origWd = origWd;
                }

                public int getOrigHt() {
                                return origHt;
                }

                public void setOrigHt(int origHt) {
                                this.origHt = origHt;
                }

}
```