# mousePressed won't respond on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, mouselistener

I am trying to write a code that when the user clicks once, a little dot shows up, twice a line forms from the first and second clicks, and third forms a triangle out of all the clicks, and clicking again restarts with a dot. Currently I can get my JFrame and JPanel to open, but clicking does nothing. I added in a System.out.print command just to see if my mousePressed method ever ran, but it never does. Here is my code currently:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TriangleClicker extends JFrame {
    private final int width = 700;
    private final int height = 800;
    private JPanel panel;
    private MouseListener listener;
    private int p1x;
    private int p1y;
    private int p2x;
    private int p2y;
    private int p3x;
    private int p3y;
    private int count = 0;
    private Graphics g;

public TriangleClicker() {
    this.setSize(width, height);
    this.add(createPanel());
    listener = new MousePressListener();
}

public JPanel createPanel() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setSize(width, height);
    return panel;
}

class MousePressListener extends JComponent implements MouseListener  {
    public void drawLine1(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(p1x, p1y, p1x, p1y);
    }

    public void drawLine2(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y);
    }

    public void drawLine3(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(p3x, p3y, p1x, p1y);
        g.drawLine(p3x, p3y, p2x, p2y);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (count == 0) {
            p1x = e.getX();
            p1y = e.getY();
            drawLine1(g);
            count++;
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        else if (count == 1) {
            p2x = e.getX();
            p2y = e.getY();
            drawLine2(g);
            count++;
        }
        else if(count == 2) {
            p3x = e.getX();
            p3y = e.getY();
            drawLine3(g);
            count++;
        }
        else if(count == 4) {
            g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            p1x = e.getX();
            p1y = e.getY();
            p2x = 0;
            p2y = 0;
            p3x = 0;
            p3y = 0;
            drawLine1(g);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `listener` is never added to anything, therefore it can't respond to input. Maybe have a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: And this looks suspiciously like [Adding a MouseListener to a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092855/adding-a-mouselistener-to-a-panel/50092971#50092971)

Comment: I *highly* recommend that you go back to your notes and ask your teacher for clarification, because both you and (what appears to suspiciously be) your fellow student and making a number of fundamental mistakes which should have been covered before the assignment was set.  You're also going to want to take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)